# Capybara/Cucumber/Ruby issue: Press element only if appears and continue without errors

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I´m really new in Capybara world and I am having lot of problems to write a test that do some operations in a screen that only appears sometimes.

I want to click in one element of this screen, if appear, but if does not appear, I need to keep clicking and fulfill a form in the next screen.

My solution now, works but it´s really ugly:

Step:

```
When(/^check my process with several screens$/) do
  page=MyPage.new
  page.check_and_click_screen1_if_appears  
  page.do_my_operations_in_screen2 
end
```

MyPage implementation:

```
def check_and_click_screen1_if_appears  
  Capybara::find_by_id("idOfOneElement", :wait => 2).click      
  rescue Capybara::ElementNotFound
end

def do_my_operations_in_screen2 
  Capybara::find_by_id("idOfOtherElement").click        
  Capybara::fill_in('txtSearch', :with => 'mytext')
end
```

If "idOfOneElement" appears in 2 seconds, click it and continue doing "check_screen2_elements", if does not appear, none error is shown in test and pass to execute "do_my_operations_in_screen2".

Works fine but I´m sure that capybara can do this much more effective!!

And if I need to improve my test, and want to fill in some text box in my optional "screen1", my solution with rescue exception does not work!!!

Some help??

Thanks!!!

Comment: did you try with `expect(page).to have_selector("something")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using find or expects you should be using Capybaras has_xxx? and has_no_xxx? methods (has_css?, has_button?, has_select?, ...) which return boolean results rather than raising expectations.  In your case it would be

```
if page.has_css?('#idOfOneElement', wait: 2) 
  page.find_by_id("idOfOneElement").click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!!

That was very useful!!!!
Final code:

```
 if Capybara::has_css?('#idOfOneElement', wait: 1)
       Capybara::fill_in('idOfOneElement', :with => 'mytext') 
       Capybara::find_by_id("idOfOneButton").click
 end
```